# Query a SQL field for whether it contains any one of multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to query the rows of SQL column for whether it contains any one of multiple values.

For instance, return rows of a table where its column A contains any of the following words:
`('cow','farmer','milk')`.

Easy enough when you know what the words are, but I want to write a sproc where I can feed in any array of strings and if the column A for a certain row contains any of them, it would return the row.

I would want to be able to feed in:

`('cow','farmer','milk')`

or

`('cow','farmer','steak','yikes')`

or

```
('cow','farmer','three', 'pigs', 'wolf')
```

It must be relatively straightforward, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out.
I'm on SQL Server 2008

Comment: Can you please show sample data? E.g. does the table contain single values in each row, or can the table also contain a string like `cow,milk`?

Comment: Sorry, the data would be whole sentences and I want to see if any of those words are present.

Comment: You can try my solution just change the JOIN to be LIKE instead of =. Can't edit properly right now from a phone.

Answer (score 17):

One simple approach:

```
declare @candidates varchar = '|cow|farmer|three|pigs|wolf|'
select * from TableName where @candidates like '%|' + FieldName + '|%'
```

The best way to do this in SQL 2008 is with a [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).

Comment: +1 - the knee-jerk reaction to this problem is to use a split function, but in this case it's just not necessary. I'd say the `LIKE` is still more efficient than TVPs, but I'm not sure as I haven't tested those directly in this use case, and I'm going to post a TVP answer anyway so the OP can test.

Comment: I think OP wants rows in which FieldName *contains* one of the words - this checks whether FieldName *equals* one of the words.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I also interpreted "_contains any one of multiple values_" as "its value corresponds to any of the values", but you may be right.

Comment: I was struggling to get this to work and found it was because FieldName for me was an nvarchar(64) and I was just declaring @candidates as nvarchar. If I explicitly state (at)candidates is a nvarchar(64) and then set it to a list it works, regardless of the size of the list.

Comment: Is there any similar solution for the case where `FieldName` is of the form `potato|monkey|pigs|carrot|sandwich` and you want to match because it contains a value from `@candidates`?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan, unfortunately nothing occurs to me. I'd be thinking very hard about either (a) normalizing the data model, or if that's too high a barrier, (b) employing a table-valued parameter in the query (in which case you can flip the logic above).

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server doesn't know what an "array" is. You can write a split table-valued function that turns each value into a row and then joins against the base table, but this is definitely sub-optimal compared to Av's answer. Or you can test that against a table-valued parameter. A TVP is [definitely the best performer compared to all of the splitting techniques, even CLR](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql).

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.FarmItems AS TABLE(Item VARCHAR(32));
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FindFarmItems
  @List dbo.FarmItems READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT t.col1, t.col2, ...
    FROM dbo.table AS t
    INNER JOIN @List AS L
    ON t.columnA = L.Item;
END
GO
```

Then in C# you just construct a DataTable with your "array" and pass it in:

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Item", typeof(string));
dt.Rows.Add("cow");
dt.Rows.Add("farmer");
...

using (SqlConnection conn = new ...)
{
    SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand("dbo.FindFarmItems", conn);
    2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter tvp = c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@List", dt);
    tvp.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    // execute, get a reader, etc...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same dilema, and came up with the following.  For example, if table_a contains ('My Cow', 'My Goat', 'My Dog') and table_b contains ('Dog', 'Cow'), then...

```
create table #table_a (field1 varchar(128))
insert into #table_a values('My Cow')
insert into #table_a values('My Goat')
insert into #table_a values('My Dog')

create table #table_b (field1 varchar(128))
insert into #table_b values('Dog')
insert into #table_b values('Cow')

select * from #table_a table_a where (select count(*) from #table_b table_b where charindex(table_b.field1, table_a.field1) > 0) > 0
```

returns ('My Cow','My Dog')

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the XML data type to pass list data to your stored procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.LookItUp

  @idList xml

as

  declare @lookup table
  (
    id int not null
  )

  insert @lookup (id)
  select distinct t.id.value('.','int')
  from @idList.nodes('/ids/id') as t( id )
  where t.id is not null

  select *
  from dbo.my_data_table t
  join @lookup           lu on lu.id = t.object_id

  return 0
go
```

Easy!

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass arrays to Stored Procedures, as arrays don't exist in TSQL. You have a few options, I'm giving you two of them.

**Option 1 - Quick and dirty** (I don't recommend it)
Pass the values as a string and add it to a dynamic SQL Statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
  @Values varchar(1000)
AS

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(2000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT blahblah WHERE SomeField IN (' + @Values + ')'

-- Execute the statement and return the result

END
```

Apart from the obvious SQL Injection vulnerability, this approach won't work for big sets and it won't perform too well either. Also, it won't work if any value contains a comma. I really don't recommend it, although it may be useful for quick testing.

**Option 2 - A more flexible solution**
Store all your values in a temporary table which you will reference in your Stored Procedure.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable
-- Fields...

INSERT INTO #MyTempTable
-- Insert the values

CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc
  @Values varchar(1000)
AS

SELECT 
  SomeFields
FROM
  MyTable
  JOIN
  #MyTempTable ON
    -- Add join clause

END
```

This solution may scale better.

As other have suggested, you can also use an in-memory table (which I personally avoid, as I never had much luck with them, they always performed worse than temporary tables), or a table parameter, but you must declare its type beforehand.

Comment: With the new info, the first solution doesn't work because you can't combine LIKE an IN. For the second one, the key part of the code is missing entirely - how to get the array of values (presumably coming from an app) into the #temp table.

Comment: The OP didn't write "LIKE" in the original post, therefore I didn't use one. Obviously, now that he clarified his needs, my solution doesn't apply anymore.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use WHERE column IN (coma separated strings)

Here is my complete example how to do that:

```
create table #bar (foo varchar(20))

insert into #bar (foo) values('cow')
insert into #bar (foo) values('cat')

select foo from #bar
where foo in ('cow','farmer','milk')

drop table #bar
```

Comment: Keyword is 'contains' not 'equals'